# Связанные таблицы в Phalcon через ORM

Tags: php, orm, phalcon, model

Имеются 2 таблицы: `users` и `rules`
Users:

```
id 
name 
login 
password 
email 
rule_id
```

Rules:

```
id 
name`
```

Также есть 2 модели:

Users:

```
class Users extends Model {  
    public $id;   
    public $name;  
    public $login;  
    public $password;  
    public $email;  
    public $rule_id;  

    public function initialize() 
    {  
        $this->hasOne("rule_id", "Rules", "id");
    }   
}
```

Rules:

```
class Rules extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "Users", "rule_id");
    }  
}
```

IndexController:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction() {
        $user = Users::findFirst(23);
        echo "Id: " . $user->id . ",
              Name: " . $user->name . ",
              Login: " . $user->login . ",
              Password: " . $user->password . ",
              Email: " . $user->email . ",
              Rule: " . $user->rules->name . "\n";
    }
}
```

Выходит следующая ошибка:

> Model 'Rules' could not be loaded

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы проверил три пункта:

**Первое.** Обратная связь для `hasMany` должна быть установлена через метод `belongsTo()`, а не `hasOne()`.

Таким образом модель Users становится такой:

```
class Users extends Model {  
    public $id;   
    public $name;  
    public $login;  
    public $password;  
    public $email;  
    public $rule_id;  

    public function initialize() 
    {  
        $this->belongsTo("rule_id", "Rules", "id");
    }   
}
```

**Второе.** Не забыли ли вы указать пространство имен?
Допустим, модели `Rules` и `Users` принадлежат пространству имен `Models`.
Тогда код будет выглядеть так:

Rules

```
class Rules extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "\Models\Users", "rule_id");
    }  
}
```

Users

```
class Users extends Model {  
    public $id;   
    public $name;  
    public $login;  
    public $password;  
    public $email;  
    public $rule_id;  

    public function initialize() 
    {  
        $this->belongsTo("rule_id", "\Models\Rules", "id");
    }   
}
```

**Третье.** Если первые два пункта не помогли, попробуйте задать `alias` вручную.

Users

```
class Users extends Model {  
    public $id;   
    public $name;  
    public $login;  
    public $password;  
    public $email;  
    public $rule_id;  

    public function initialize() 
    {  
        // На всякий случай проверьте alias и в нижнем регистре
        $this->belongsTo("rule_id", "\Models\Rules", "id", array('alias' => 'Rules'));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, ошибка пропала, но теперь возникла другая проблема как вывести связанное поле?        $user = Users::findFirst(23);  
        echo "Id: " . $user->id . ",
              Name: " . $user->name . ",
              Login: " . $user->login . ",
              Password: " . $user->password . ",
              Email: " . $user->email . ",
              Rule: " . $user->rules->id . "\n";

Comment: Вы проверяли содержимое `$user->rules`? Что выводит `var_dump($user->rules);`? Вы пробовали сменить регистр `alias`а?

Comment: Выводит null, я без alias создал

Comment: Проверьте вручную, существует ли в таблице `rules` запись с `id` равным `rule_id` для записи #23 в таблице `users`. Похоже на пустую выборку.

Comment: Да, существует,   Вот код ошибки   `Notice: Access to undefined property Multiple\Backend\Models\Users::rules in C:\xampp\htdocs\progbook.uz\apps\backend\controllers\IndexController.php on line 14
NULL`

Comment: Попробуйте все-таки указать `alias`. Связь не подцепилась.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, получилось, через добавление alias.